# Is there a way to pass multiple values to macro function as single defined macro value in C?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, avr

I want to declare pin definition in global header as a simple line like:

```c
#define STATUS_LED B,7
```

Then I want to pass this pin definition to function above:

```c
CMBset_out(STATUS_LED);
```

I don't know how to approach this - MY_PIN is in proper format to be replaced during precompilation phase.

```c
#define CMBsbi(port, pin) (PORT##port) |= (1<<pin)
#define CMBset_out(port,pin) (DDR##port) |= (1<<pin)
// define pins 
#define STATUS_LED B,7
```

Then, I want to pass this pin definition to function above (`hw_init_states()` is declared in the same header file called from main C file):

```
// runtime initialization
void hw_init_states(){
#ifdef STATUS_LED
    CMBset_out(STATUS_LED);
#endif
}
```

But I get a compilation error:

```
Error   1   macro "CMBset_out" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given   GENET_HW_DEF.h  68  23  Compass IO_proto
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An improvement upon the previous answer, which also allows you to call the macro with two explicit arguments.

It should work with any c99 (or better) compiler:

```
#define CMBset_out_X(port,pin) (DDR##port) |= (1<<pin)
#define CMBset_out(...) CMBset_out_X(__VA_ARGS__)

#define STATUS_LED B,7
CMBset_out(STATUS_LED)
CMBset_out(B, 7)
```

Comment: @bajtec basically, the arguments to a function-like macro are replaced as-is (without being macro-expanded) in the macro's "replacement list" (right side), and then the result is recursively scanned for _other_ macros. The arguments are "lazily evaluated" ie they're expanded after, not before they were passed to a macro. Sorry if that's not the best explanation ;-)

Comment: Almost... "the arguments to a function-like macro are replaced as-is (without being macro expanded)" ...if the parameter in the replacement list is being pasted/stringified.  E.g. in this CMBset_out, `__VA_ARGS__` is neither, `STATUS_LED` is expanded (6.10.3.1) yielding `B,7` before the result's rescanned, which is what makes this solution work (without this, you would have `CMBset_out_X(STATUS_LED)` being rescanned, which we already know doesn't work!)

Comment: @HWalters You're right, I've skipped a step. But the base is right -- the arguments are still expanded _after_ they were passed to a macro -- otherwise it would be too late to forego expanding them when they're pasted/stringified in the replacement list.

Answer (score 7):

It *is* possible, but you need another level of macros to expand the argument:

```
#define CMBset_out_X(port,pin) (DDR##port) |= (1<<pin)
#define CMBset_out(x) CMBset_out_X(x)
```

Of course this means that you can't use the `CMBset_out` macro with two explicit arguments.

Comment: @mosvy , can you elaborate more ? how this construction works ?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly that works ? why do i need two level macro that seems doing nothing?

Comment: @bajtec: because the preprocessor runs in passes; the first pass replaces `CMBset_out(STATUS_LED)` with `CMBset_out_X(B,7)`, and then the 2nd pass replaces the `CMBset_out_X` macro.